# Which "God" is Luke referring to?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, religion, luke-skywalker

From *A New Hope*'s [transcript](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-A-New-Hope.html):

> LUKE:
>                                 (sighing)
>                            Oh, God, my uncle. How am I ever 
>                            going to explain this?

This is most-likely a form of [Early Installment Weirdness](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EarlyInstallmentWeirdness) (Warning, yadda yadda) given that as far as I know, none of the other films ever mention a "Capital G-God," either religiously or through slang and either the Force or various minor gods are generally believed in.

Similarly, "Hell" was mentioned a few times in the films. Eventually, it was explained that Hell was another name for [Chaos](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Chaos), so I'm wondering if a similar retcon was ever made to explain this.

**My question is, did the EU ever explain which God Luke was referencing?**

Comment: Probably not an answer to the question, but a fun related fact: the Corellian religion was described as having Hell, so Han could say things like "what the Hell was that?" and have it not be an anachronism

Comment: https://xkcd.com/890/

Comment: Not directly. The closest we ever find to religion on Tattooine is from pre-Disney excellent *"Kenobi"* book by Miller which describes in detail Tusken religion

Comment: I'm going to go with [Translation Convention](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TranslationConvention).  Caution - TVTropes!

Comment: Probably just a generic swear word held over from a time when religion was more prevalent.

Comment: Hopefully [this one](http://cdn.pauldwaite.me.uk/images/space-ganesha.png).

Comment: @DVK - the Jedi Order is a religion - I'd say that counts! Both in universe and out of universe :) - it's even called a religion in Episode 4

Comment: (moved my answer to a comment since it didn't fully address the question as stated:

The film itself doesn't contain that reference - he simply says "my uncle - how am I every going to explain this?"

The Star Wars universe does not appear to be absent of the concept of religion -

"Your sad devotion to that ancient religion has not helped you conjure up the stolen data tapes" - Imperial Officer - EIV

"They appear to think I am some sort of god!" "Well why don't you use your divine influence, and get us out of this?" "It's against my programming to impersonate a deity" - C-3P0 / Han Solo- EVI

Comment: @NathanK.Campbell if you can find a video clip of that scene in which Luke does not actually say that, I think the fact that he doesn't say it counts as an answer.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YZ_mjtTCdcg&t=400 - 6:50 into the clip

Comment: It's a figure of speech

Comment: @NKCampbell arguably, the religion being referred to in Ep 4 is actually the Sith, since Vader is a devoted Sith by this point. Luke later refers to "the Jedi religion" in Ep 7.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the *film* he does ***not*** say "God", he sighs and mumbles something unintelligible (possibly "oh boy, my uncle")

listen closely at 3:56

Comment: There's a version with somewhat better sound quality here, the line happens at 3:56 in this version: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pUaxXsqGeFI ...I think it's definitely "oh, boy". That's also how it's written in [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=vrZiAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT124&ots=6b_55rQ8s_&dq=%22oh%20boy%20my%20uncle%22%20luke%20star%20wars&pg=PT124#v=onepage&q=%22oh%20boy%20my%20uncle%22%20luke%20star%20wars&f=false).